# Maven : get version from dependency of the present dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have a pom.xml that contains some projects

```
<groupId>org.company</groupId>
<artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-one</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-two</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Now, i initialized an other project and its pom.xml as below

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-iterator.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>iterator</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <items>
                          <item>project-one</item>
                          <item>project-two</item>
                        </items>
                        <pluginExecutors>
                            <pluginExecutor>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                                <configuration>
                                  <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                      <groupId>org.company</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>@item@</artifactId>
                                      <version>???</version> <!-- I need to specify the version that is in the aggregator pom.xml --> 
                                      <type>jar</type>
                                      <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                      <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/Directory/@item@</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                  </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                          </pluginExecutor>
                        </pluginExecutors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I tried to remove the  field and I thought maven would look for the version specified in the dependency for exemple :
project-one.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
project-two.1.0.2-SNAPSHOT

but it didn't work.

Is there a way to handle versions through dependencies ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate more in detail what you exactly like to achieve? What kind of project should be built?

Comment: both are already built, the second pom.xml only copy the correspondant *.jars into a specific directory. The need is to retrieve version of artifacts already built by the aggregator (1st pom.xml)

Comment: Why are doing that via iterator plugin? Is this project a war/ear project? Or might it be better to use maven-assembly-plugin? And maybe you need to think about a multi module build?=